# Obtaining type class from java class using reflections

Tags: java, reflection

I currently have a setup like this:

```java
public abstract class Configurable<T> {
    //...
}
```

```java
public class ConfigurableBoolean extends Configurable<Boolean> {
    //...
}
```

I'm looking to obtain a Boolean class from ConfigurableBoolean but Integer on a ConfigurableInt (similar setup)

Comment: `((ParameterizedType) ConfigurableBoolean.class.getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's just "one step" (the direct superclass of the type you're inspecting is `Configurable<C>` where `C` is a non-parametrized class), then it's

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") <T> Class<? extends T> getConfigType(Class<? extends Configurable<? extends T>> clazz) {
    String err = "configuration type of " + clazz + " is too hard to find";
    if(!(clazz.getGenericSuperclass() instanceof ParameterizedType)) throw new UnsupportedOperationException(err);
    var configurable = (ParameterizedType)clazz.getGenericSuperclass();
    if(configurable.getRawType() != Configurable.class) throw new UnsupportedOperationException(err);
    var args = configurable.getActualTypeArguments();
    if(args.length != 1 || !(args[0] instanceof Class)) throw new UnsupportedOperationException(err);
    return (Class<? extends T>)args[0];
}
```

You could modify this to search "harder": recursing up the superclasses until it finds `Configurable`, and maybe even tracking the assignments of type parameters so it can handle things like

```
class ConfigurableList<T> extends Configurable<List<T>> { }
class ConfigurableListBoolean extends ConfigurableList<Boolean> { }
```

but otherwise this seems to handle your case.